# Magento: programmatically set free shipping

Tags: magento

I am programming a module where I need to set free shipping of a quote on a certain occasions. I am trying to get this working:

```
$quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setFreeShipping(1);
```

but so far no success. Can anyone help?

EDIT: I need to do this from on the following events:

```
checkout_cart_update_items_after
checkout_cart_product_add_after
sales_quote_remove_item
```

Basically upon any cart modification I need to determine if shipping should be free of charge.

EDIT: This seems to work pretty well. Except I would need to disable free shipping as a choice in checkout.

```
$address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
$address->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping');
```

Answer (score 4):

you can first identify your event for which you want to set free shipping and based on that event you can set free shipping as your default option.

Below code might help you a bit.

app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml:

```
// find methods loop:
 <?php foreach ($_rates as $_rate): ?>

//  add checking for free shipping method and setting it as default
<?php if ($_rate->getCode()=='freeshipping_freeshipping' && !$this->getAddress()->getShippingMethod()) {
      $this->getAddress()->setShippingMethod($_rate->getCode());
} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! freeshipping_freeshipping is probably a way.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is by adding your own "quote address total" the same way as it's done in SalesRule module by  `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Freeshipping` class. To replicate this, you need to create a class extending `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract` and inside it a method named `collect()` like this:

```
class Mycompany_Mymod_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Freeshipping extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract
{
    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
    {
        parent::collect($address);
        if(somecondition){
            $address->setFreeShipping(true);
        }
    }
}
```

and then declare your custom "quote address total" in your module config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <sales>
            <quote>
                <totals>
                    <customfreeshipping>
                        <class>mymodname/sales_quote_address_total_freeshipping</class>
                        <after>freeshipping</after> <!-- this ensures our custom total is placed after Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Freeshipping so we can override "$address->setFreeShipping(0);" -->
                    </customfreeshipping>
                </totals>
            </quote>
        </sales>
    </global>
</config>
```

This will declare free shipping on address object that will be passed on to the request object by `$request->setFreeShipping($this->getFreeShipping());` in `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` class within `requestShippingRates()` method and then will be available for any shipping module that is checking for `$request->getFreeShipping()`.

Enjoy :)

Comment: What is global > sales > quote > totals section in the XML? It neither seems a model nor seems to be configuration path.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you just save your quote ?

```
$quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setFreeShipping(1);
$quote->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the following Magento 2 error

> Please specify a shipping method

And this code solve the problem :

```
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                ->collectShippingRates()
                ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
```

Also check the proper solution from [Unable to set Shipping Method in Magento order create script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056215/unable-to-set-shipping-method-in-magento-order-create-script/20165113#20165113)