# Unable to set Shipping Method in Magento order create script

Tags: php, magento-1.7

I am having trouble getting my Script to create an order on my live site that uses Magento 1.7. The error I am getting is “please specify a shipping method” more detail is

> blockquote Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Please specify a shipping method.' in /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php:594 Stack trace: #0 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(303): Mage::throwException('Please specify ...') #1 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(222): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->_validate() #2 /home/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Service/Quote.php(238): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitNominalItems() #3 /home/mysite/public_html/apitest/magento_order_create.php(82): Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Quote->submitAll() #4 {main} thrown in /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 594

I am trying to use the script below to create the order and I am passing the skus and quantities in the post from another page. `

```
<?php
// Link Mage Class
require ('../app/Mage.php');


// Initialize Magento framework
Mage::app('mysite');


//create a cart 
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
 ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('mysite')->getId());


//Get Customer by Id
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load('1');

//attach customer to cart 
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);

//attach products
foreach ($_POST as $sku=>$qty)
    {

        $product =     Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($sku,Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(), 'sku');
    $buyInfo = array(
        'qty' => $qty,
        // custom option id => value id
        // or
        // configurable attribute id => value id
        );
    $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($buyInfo));

}
//get and set customer billing address
//need to work on this encase we use diffrent billing and shipping addresses
$addressData = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load('1');


$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);

// set shipping and payment methods. assumes freeshipping and check payment
// have been enabled.
/*
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping')
        ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
*/

// THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR SEEMS TO BE
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); 
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();

//set payment method     
$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));


//save cart and check out
$quote->collectTotals()->save();


$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
$order = $service->getOrder();

printf("Created order %s\n", $order->getIncrementId());
`
```

The above script originally came from http://pastebin.com/8cft4d8v
and it works like a charm on my test environment (also 1.7). I have commented out the original shipping method code and broke is out into separate lines. 
The live site has two sites and two stores, I have made sure that free shipping is enabled on the backend and tested that it shows up when I run this script.

```
<?php

// Link Mage Class
require ('../app/Mage.php');

// Initialize Magento framework
Mage::app('mysite');

$methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();

var_dump($methods);
```

I am fairly certain the address is set correctly, if I echo is out to the screen that address is there.

I have tried reading the documentation, looking at other sample code and changing parts of it to see if I can get the shipping method set, but no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well the main solution seems to be something that was solved during a server reboot. But I am also going to post the final script that we are going to use. For some reason setting shipping method on a quote object does not seem to work, so I also went back to the “orginal” script that I had found on http://pastebin.com/8cft4d8v. I also got rid of some lines that did not seem to matter if they existed or not. Hope this may help someone down the line

```
<?php

// Link Mage Class
require ('..\app\Mage.php');


// Initialize Magento framework
Mage::app('my');

//create a cart 
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());


//Get Customer by Id
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load('1');

//attach customer to cart 
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);

//attach products
foreach ($_POST as $sku=>$qty)
{

    $product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($sku, Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(), 'sku');
    $buyInfo = array(
        'qty' => $qty,
        // custom option id => value id
        // or
        // configurable attribute id => value id
    );
    $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($buyInfo));

}


$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData();
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData();

// set shipping and payment methods. assumes freeshipping and check payment
// have been enabled.   
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
        ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');


$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));


//save cart and check out
$quote->collectTotals()->save();



$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
$order = $service->getOrder();

printf("Created order %s\n", $order->getIncrementId());
```

Comment: I get: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Varien_Object::addData(), 0 passed